# Google Visualization Pie Chart onclick event not firing in IE8

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using the Google Visualization API to draw a pie chart with some data.

I'm also adding an onclick event, which works perfectly in Chrome.  But the event does seem to be firing at all in IE8.  No error--it just doesn't fire at all.

The chart renders perfectly in all browsers--but the onclick event is not working in IE8 (and possibly other versions of IE--haven't yet tested).

Any ideas?

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('string');
    dataTable.addColumn('number');
    $.each(obj_json_data,function(){
        dataTable.addRow([this.Name,this.Number]);
    });

    var options = {cht:  'p3', chs: '600x225', labels:'name', legend:'none',
                   chds:'0,160', enableEvents:true, chdls:'000000,14'};

    var chart = new  google.visualization.ImageChart(document.getElementById('chart_container'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);

    // Assign  event  handler
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onclick', mouseEventHandler);

function mouseEventHandler(event) {
    alert('You just clicked ' + event.region);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In line: google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onclick', mouseEventHandler);

Try pointing the listener to the 'select' event instead of the 'onclick' event.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'onclick', it's 'click' event